# Can I publish one app with different styles?

Tags: android, google-play

I have a app where are storys in different categories. I want to publish for every category a own app in google play store (same design), but as a paid app i will publish on APP with all categories and stories.

Is it allow in google play store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it, you have some categorys. For each category you want to make one free app.

==> And you want to publish one paid App witch contains all of the categorys.

Correct me if I didn't get it right.

I didn't know any reason why it shouldn't be allowed in the Google Play Store. I think you dont have to worry.

Comment: Yes, you get it. :) Thanks.